# Why does ServerXMLHttp timeout when XMLHttp doesn't?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, dynamics-nav, serverxmlhttp

I'm trying to 'GET' this file (http://www.nbp.pl/Kursy/xml/dir.txt) with ServerXMLHttp 6.0, but it timeouts for somewhat reason.

Though XMLHttp works fine on the same URL with the same code..

```
IF ISCLEAR(XmlHttp) THEN
  CREATE(XmlHttp);
XmlHttp.open('GET','http://www.nbp.pl/Kursy/xml/dir.txt',FALSE,'','');
XmlHttp.setTimeouts(900000, 900000, 900000, 900000); // Only applicable to ServerXMlHttp
XmlHttp.send();
```

The code above applies to both ServerXMLHttp and XMLHttp. Only the setTimeouts methods is used for ServerXMLHttp only.

Any ideas why could one work and the other fail?

Comment: I bet it have something to do with WinHTTP proxy settings which is only used by ServerXMLHttp and not by XMLHttp. Try read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761351(v=vs.85).aspx). Also you could try set your network credentials explicitly.

Comment: Actually you're right @MakSim, I've totally forgot that I've to set proxy. Though I don't get timeout anymore - I don't get response either.. Will look into it..

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was pointed out in Mak Sim comment.

You need to add this line before Open method when using serverXMLHttp:

```
XmlHttp.setProxy(2,SOME_PROXY);
```